# Parent window actions suspended when a MessageBox is shown

Tags: c++, qt, qmessagebox

I have a Qt front end application, which connects to a back
end server in a different machine. And it keeps sending the heart beat messages to inform that it's alive.

The problem is when a QMessageBox is shown (using `QMessageBox::warning(...)`), it suspends the activity of the
parent application, which causes to miss sending the heart beats, which
ultimately results in disconnection due to heart beat miss count exceed.

The requirement is to disallow the user to interact with the other windows if there is an error message being shown.

What is the most efficient and convenient way of doing this?

Comment: How are you sending the heartbeats? Qt timers normally aren't suspended by modal windows (although, generally the communication protocol handling is done in a separate thread exactly to avoid this kind of problems).

Comment: You could create a own QThread for your heartbeat messages, this would run independent from any action in the main thread.

Comment: `QMessageBox` causes rest of GUI to freeze untill message box is dismissed, if you base hartbeats upon other GUI elements - maybe that's the case, I'd reccomend you to use [QTimer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtimer.html#details) from non-gui thread with [QThread::exec](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthread.html#exec) or check QNetworAccessManager as @0x35 suggested.

Answer (score 1):

If you send your messages and do some background stuff in main thread, you can get some window "freeze". It's better to do all the background stuff in another thread.

If sending of messages is all what you doing in the background, it's maybe enough to use timers because [`QNetworkAccessManager`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) doing it asynchronously, without blocking a current thread.

> QNetworkAccessManager has an asynchronous API. When the replyFinished slot above is called, the parameter it takes is the QNetworkReply object containing the downloaded data as well as meta-data (headers, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `QMessageBox::warning()`, create an instance of `QMessageBox` and show it using `::open()` method. Unlike `::warning()` this function will not block your application.

Make sure that parent of QMessageBox is set as your window, otherwise it won't prevent the user interaction with the window.